# Where do I save .ui files from QT creator when using pyside-uic?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, qt-creator, pyside

When running pyside-uic.exe mainwindow.ui I get the error:
 No such file or directory: "mainwindow.ui"

It still generates the file mainwindow.py, there's just nothing in it.  My assumption is that QT creator is not saving the ui file to the right place, and I've tried changing it with no success.  Where should the save location be?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried giving pyside-uic.exe an absolute path to the .ui file?

Comment: Yes, when I give it an absolute path it works.  However, when I added it to the path windows environment variable it didn't work.  This is ok for now, but I'd hate to have to type the whole path every time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that when you type "pyside-uic mainwindow.ui" you are in the directory where .ui is? Is it listed after "dir" command? Can you show us how your pyside-uic command looks?

Comment: Ok, when I put pyside-uic and the .ui file in the same folder it works fine.  I thought I tried that earlier but I guess not!